# gnu screen emacs ess: M-X R freeze

Tags: ess, r

I just pick up emacs after a while with Vim.
This is run on CentOS server. 
I ssh to the server, and start with gnu screen, and emacs ess, when I start to run R, emacs just freeze.

Here is what I did before it get freeze:

```
ssh servername
screen
emacs -nw test.r
C-X 2
C-X o
M-X R
```

the process of emacs is still running with CPU 80-90%. And there is no R process coming up.

It is fine if I run emacs without screen.

Any suggestion for getting this work?

Comment: Are you using a custom prompt? If so, try without the prompt.